# What is the proper term for immediate referencing?

Tags: php, javascript, syntax, language-agnostic, terminology

This is an extremely noob question. It's very difficult to google, because I don't know what it is. ;)

I'm looking for the term for immediately referencing data. JavaScript supports this, as does Perl and many others.

In JS you would do this:

```
MyObject.giveMeAnArray()[4].myMethod()
```

While in PHP, you would have to do this:

```
$myArray = $MyObject->giveMeAnArray();
$myArray[4]->myMethod();
```

What is the proper **term** for this kind of immediate referencing syntax?

Comment: I don't think there is a term for that. It's not a feature in other languages, but a problem with PHP which doesn't allow this syntax.

Comment: @Anurag A friend just mentioned the term "dereferencing".

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate term would be [JavaScript operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3ks45k7), in which array subscript notation has the same weight as parentheses. In [PHP operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), array subscript notation has more weight, which causes the above to fail.

`Function array dereferencing` is the marketing name in PHP 5.3+.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Thank you. BTW, just for reference, you can do this in PHP 5.3+ (thankfully). You can also do abbreviated array notation with [], removing the need for the Array() function call. Makes things quite a bit cleaner to look at.